# Is there a way to specify a "master" or "index" migration?

Tags: python-3.x, django, wagtail, django-migrations

I'm working on an existing Django 2.2 application comprising a custom app in conjunction with a Wagtail CMS, where I'm iteratively adding new wagtail page-types in separate user stories over time.

I want to be able to create a "master" or "index" migration that pre-builds each page-type in the database automatically when migrations are run (ours are performed in an Ansible task upon deployment). As far as I can tell, what I need requires:

1. The auto-built migration that modifies the DB schema for each page
2. A further migration that is always run *last* and which contains a `dependencies` attr - able to be updated with a single list-entry representing the new page's migration name, each time one is added.

I can already auto-build page-types using the following logic in a `create()` method called from `migrations.RunPython()` but at the moment, this *same* page-build logic needs to exist in *each* page's migration - I'd prefer it if this existed in a *single* migration (or an alternative procedure if one exists in DJango) that can always be run.

Ideally, the `page_types` list below could be replaced by just iterating over `BasePage.__subclasses__()`, (Where all page-types inherit from `BasePage`) meaning this "master" migration need never be altered again.

Note: if it helps any, the project is still in development, so any solution that is slightly controversial or strictly "dev-only" is acceptable - assuming it can be made acceptable and therefore less controversial by merging migrations later.

```
...
...

# Fetch the pre-created, root Page"
root_page = BasePage.objects.all().first()
page_types = [
    ManageAccountPage,
    EditUserDetailPage,
]
path_init = int('000100020003') # The last value for `path` from 0007_initialise_site_ttm.py

# Create, then add all child pages
for page_type in page_types:
    title_raw = page_type.__name__.replace('Page', '')

    page = page_type(
        title=utils.convert_camel_to_human(title_raw),
        slug=title_raw.lower(),
        show_in_menus='t',
        content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(page_type),
        path=path_init + 1,
        depth=2
    )

    try:
        root_page.add_child(instance=page)
    except exceptions.ValidationError:
        continue

...
...
```

What's the problem?

(See "What I've tried" below)

What I've tried:

- A custom `pin_curr_migration()` method called from `migrations.RunPython()` that deletes the "master" migration's own record in `django_migrations` allowing it to be re-run. This however, results in errors where DJango complains about previously built pages already existing.

Comment: I have _no idea_ why someone would downvote this as a question.

Comment: Looking at the vote history, some automated process triggered the downvote and has now been run to cancel that out.